# MouseInputListener on Arc2D java

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

I am developing some visualization in java. I have a problem though. I am drawing an Arc2D in my program, and I want to add a MouseInputListener to my Arc2D. The problem is, an Arc2D object stretches over a rectangle, and not just the line which is beeing drawn. So when I want to get a mouseover effect, its for the entire rectangle and not just the line of the Arc2D. Do any of you have a solution to this problem?

My code looks like this:

```
final Arc2D arc =
   new Arc2D.Double(x_pos, 10, x2_pos-x_pos, 190, 0, 360, Arc2D.OPEN);
JPanel jp = new JPanel();
addMouseInputListener(new MouseInputAdapter() {
   @Override
   public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
      System.out.println( "X: " + e.getX() + " Y: " + e.getY() +
         " Does it touch the arc?: " + arc.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()));
   }
   // More MouseInputListener methods... 
});
ga.draw(arc);
```

Comment: Have you examined the arc's `PathIterator`?

Comment: contains is a method of Shape (closed shape), an area not a curve.

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the **distance of the point from the curve**. Then see if it's within an appropriate distance from the curve. You wouldn't want a hotspot that's only 1 pixel thick?!

To do this is not as easy as it might seem. you'll need to take

```
rsquared = pow((e.getX()-circle_centre.x),2) + pow(e.getY()-circle_centre.y,2);
```

and then see if it lies in an interval

```
rsquared<circle_radius+threshold && rsquared>circle_radius-threshold
```

And then check the angle

```
angle = Math.atan2(e.getX()-circle_centre.y, e.getY()-circle_centre.y);
```

which must lie in the interval you want as well.

Comment: This would work for a circle, but what if I draw the arc as an ellipse instead of a circle?